# Como me conecto a um SSID selecionado pelo usuário?

Tags: java, android, raspberry-pi

Estou realizando minha tese e estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo Android para configurar dispositivos domésticos [Iot](http://www.globalcode.com.br/surfboard/) (wifi).
Neste caso, os dispositivos estão sendo simulados usando um Rspberry Pi 3, que cria um ponto de acesso (portal cativo, sem senha) com um nome conhecido, ou seja, AutoDevAP-NameOfDevice.
Minha aplicação está mostrando o SSID existente no alcance do smartphone e permite que o usuário selecione um dos SSIDs e se conecte (neste caso, o aplicativo só é implementado para se conectar com este tipo de SSID.

O problema é: depois que o usuário selecionar o SSID para se conectar (AutoDevAP-SmartSwitch) eu iniciar outra atividade para se conectar a este ssid, no entanto estou preso porque o smartphone nunca se conecta a ele e estou usando a mesma lógica que tenho Usado para desenvolver um aplicativo para sempre se conectar ao mesmo SSID sem senha, mas não vai funcionar.
Inicialmente eu ensinei que o problema estava no adaptador de ouvinte, mas eu depurei o código e não é esse problema.

Meu código: 
MainACtivity.java

```js
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
    import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
    import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.ToggleButton;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    
    
        WifiManager wifiManager;
        private BroadcastReceiver wifiReciever;
        private ArrayAdapter adapter;
        ListView listview ;
        private String nameOfDev;
        private Handler mainHandler;
        private Thread connectAPThread;
        static String info = null;
        static String ssidInfo;
        static String devName;
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            listview= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter
                    (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    
            wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            mainHandler = new Handler(this.getMainLooper());
    
    
            wifiReciever = new WiFiScanReceiver();
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    
                    String s = listview.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                    info =s;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), info, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ssidInfo= getSSIDInfo(info);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ssidInfo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    devName=getDeviceName(info);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), devName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ConnectWifiActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("ssid",ssidInfo);
                    intent.putExtra("devName",devName);
                    startActivity(intent);
    
                }
            });
        }
    
    
        public String getSSIDInfo(String s){
            String[] things = s.split(",");
            String[] cenas = things[0].split(":");
            String ssid = cenas[1];
    //        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ssid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), nameOfDev, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           return ssid;
    
        }
    
        public String getDeviceName(String s){
            String[] things = s.split(",");
            String[] cenas = things[0].split(":");
            String ssid = cenas[1];
    //        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ssid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String[] outras = ssid.split("-");
            String nameOfDev = outras[1];
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), nameOfDev, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return nameOfDev;
    
        }
        public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    
            adapter.clear();
    
            ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) view;
    
            if (wifiManager == null) {
                // Device does not support Wi-Fi
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oop! Your device does not support Wi-Fi",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                toggleButton.setChecked(false);
    
            } else {
                if (toggleButton.isChecked()) { // To turn on Wi-Fi
    
    
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wi-Fi is turning on." +
                                        "\n" + "Scanning for access points...",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wi-Fi is already turned on." +
                                        "\n" + "Scanning for access points...",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     wifiManager.startScan();
    
                } else { // To turn off Wi-Fi
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wi-Fi is turned off.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }
    
   
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Register the BroadcastReceiver for SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(wifiReciever, filter);
    }
    
        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.wi_fi, menu);
            return true;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    
   
    
        class WiFiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION.equals(action)) {
                    List<ScanResult> wifiScanResultList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
                    for(int i = 0; i < wifiScanResultList.size(); i++){
                        String hotspot = (wifiScanResultList.get(i)).toString();
                        adapter.add(hotspot);
    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

```
activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="bernardo.autodevconfiguration.MainActivity">

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:textOn="Wi-Fi On"
        android:textOff="Wi-Fi Off"
        android:onClick="onToggleClicked"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toggleButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ConnectWifiACtivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by bernardo on 19-03-2017.
 */

public class ConnectWifiActivity extends Activity {


    private WifiManager wifiManager;
    private Handler mainHandler;

    private String ssid;
    private String devName;
    private Button connectButton;

    private Thread wifiThread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connctwifi);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        ssid= intent.getStringExtra("ssid");
        devName=intent.getStringExtra("devName");
        connectButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connect);

        connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //connectToAP();
                wifiThread = new Thread(runnable, "turn-on wifi");
                wifiThread.start();


            }
        });
        mainHandler = new Handler(this.getMainLooper());

    }


    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {





        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
                    Log.d("State", "wifi-on");
                    WifiConfiguration wfc = new WifiConfiguration();

                    wfc.SSID = "\"".concat(ssid).concat("\"");
                    wfc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED;
                    wfc.priority = 40;
                    wfc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
                    wfc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
                    wfc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
                    wfc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.clear();
                    wfc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
                    wfc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
                    wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
                    wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
                    wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
                    wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);


                    int networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wfc);
                    if (networkId != -1) {
                        // success, can call wfMgr.enableNetwork(networkId, true) to connect
                        wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("not connected", "trying to connect");
                    Log.d("State", "set wifi on");

                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                    WifiConfiguration wfc = new WifiConfiguration();

                    wfc.SSID = "\"".concat(ssid).concat("\"");
                    wfc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED;
                    wfc.priority = 40;
                    wfc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
                    wfc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
                    wfc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
                    wfc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.clear();
                    wfc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
                    wfc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
                    wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
                    wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
                    wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
                    wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);


                    int networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wfc);
                    if (networkId != -1) {
                        // success, can call wfMgr.enableNetwork(networkId, true) to connect
                        wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };


}
```

activity_connctwifi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="bernardo.autodevconfiguration.ConnectWifiActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="Connect to your device"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/connect"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="109dp"
        android:onClick="selfDestruct"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="bernardo.autodevconfiguration">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <!--<action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />-->


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="bernardo.autodevconfiguration.ConnectWifiActivity">

            </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow in Portuguese. In case you haven't noticed, this is the SO Portuguese community, if you're looking to get help in english please visit the [SO English Community](http://stackoverflow.com/questions). If you're looking to get help in portuguese, please edit and translate your question.

Comment: O titulo tambem deveria ser traduzido.

Comment: vacilo meu, espera